# Collapsibile list of android application in my device?

Tags: android, button, android-listview, collapsable

Starting from this code

```
class PackageInfoData{
    private String appname = "";
    private String pname = "";
    private String versionName = "";
    private int versionCode = 0;
    private Drawable icon;
}

private void getInstalledPackages() {
    ArrayList<PackageInfoData> installedApps = getInstalledApps(false); /* false = no system packages */
    for (int i=0; i<installedApps.size(); i++) {
       Log.i("Instlled app","APp Name:"+installedApps.get(i).appname+"package:"+installedApps.get(i).pname);
    }
    return installedApps ;
}

private ArrayList<PackageInfoData> getInstalledApps(boolean getSysPackages) {
    ArrayList<PackageInfoData> res = new ArrayList<PackageInfoData>();        
    List<PackageInfo> packs = getPackageManager().getInstalledPackages(0);
    for(int i=0;i<packs.size();i++) {
        PackageInfo p = packs.get(i);
        if ((!getSysPackages) && (p.versionName == null)) {
            continue ;
        }
        PackageInfoDatanewInfo = new PackageInfoData();
        newInfo.appname = p.applicationInfo.loadLabel(getPackageManager()).toString();
        newInfo.pname = p.packageName;
        newInfo.versionName = p.versionName;
        newInfo.versionCode = p.versionCode;
        newInfo.icon = p.applicationInfo.loadIcon(getPackageManager());
        res.add(newInfo);
    }
    return res; 
}
```

That returns a list of applications installed in the device, i want that this list is collapsibile. So for example, i have a button and when i click it the list will appears and when i click again the button the list disappears. How can i do it?

Comment: Like an ExpandableListView, then?

Comment: Yes something like that.

Comment: but with my code i mean..

Comment: You already have the data in a `List`. You should be able to follow any tutorial to change that into an `ExpandableListView`. Here's one to start with, you can Google for others: http://theopentutorials.com/tutorials/android/listview/android-expandable-list-view-example/

Comment: You can add a button somewhere and you can hide the list on button click with this `list.setVisibility(View.GONE)`. Or if you are using ListFragment or ListActivity you can use `setListShown()` function

Comment: What you suggest? ExpandableListView or list.setVisibility(View.GONE)?